# Query MySQL using Joomla syntax

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

The following query is returning the result I expected:

```
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass');
    if(!$link){
    echo "No connection!";
    exit();
    }

    if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8'))
    {
      echo 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
      exit();
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($link, 'database')){
        echo "No database";
    exit();
};

$res = $link->query("SELECT rules FROM xmb9d_viewlevels WHERE id=10");

while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
    echo " cenas = " . $row['rules'] . "\n";
};
```

But, since I'm using Joomla 2.5.16 and I'm trying to keep its syntax, I tried:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 

$res = $db->query("SELECT rules FROM #__viewlevels WHERE id=10");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " cenas = " . $row['rules'] . "\n";
};
```

This isn't working. It is only displaying the text " cenas =".

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you please var_dump $res and post it here

Comment: Yes, it is returning:  object(mysqli_result)#1097 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('rules'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__viewlevels'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote('10'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $results as $result) {
   echo " cenas = " . $result->rules;
}
```

Comment: Hey, you rock. As you can see, I'm doing what I can to keep up with this syntax...